# How to create and display custom Jekyll meta data

Tags: frontend, jekyll, metadata, liquid

I've got a Jekyll private blog (i.e., laboratory notebook) that uses the wonderful [minimal-mistakes](https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/) theme. I make heavy use of tags for each of my blog posts and can see the list of tags.

I also like to keep track of the people I mention in my blog post, so I add additional meta data for each post like this:

```
---
title: "My great experiment"
tags:
  - physics
  - chemistry
  - Higgs boson
people:
  - Albert Einstein
  - Galileo Galilei
  - Marie Curie
---
```

What I'd like to do is see all the people that are mentioned in my blog---across all the blog posts---but Jekyll doesn't seem to populate the `site.people` variable. I've tried to visualize just the `site.people` variable like this:

```
{
{
"people": [
    {%- for person in site.people -%}
    "{{ person[0] }}"{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
    {%- endfor -%}
],

}
}
```

but all that I see on the rendered web page is:

```
{ { “people”: [],

} }
```

**What do I need to do so Jekyll will see the people meta data?** Do I need to somehow tell Jekyll there's other meta data that it needs to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace `site` with `page` in your second code snippet, see the handling for [variables](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/).

- site: global website (e.g. _config.yml)
- page: current page

Additional I dropped the array index `[0]`.

```
{
{
"people": [
    {%- for person in page.people -%}
    "{{ person }}"{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
    {%- endfor -%}
],

}
}
```

My Output / The result

```json
{ { “people”: [“Albert Einstein”,”Galileo Galilei”,”Marie Curie”],

} }
```

Update 2020-10-23:

A snippet of the global `_config.yml` to declare all the physicists.

```yaml
...

physicists:
  - Albert Einstein
  - Galileo Galilei
  - Marie Curie
  - Isaac Newton
  - Nikola Tesla
  - Max Planck

...
```

To get the list of all physicists on any post

```
---
title: "My great experiment"
tags:
  - physics
  - chemistry
  - Higgs boson
people:
  - Albert Einstein
  - Galileo Galilei
  - Marie Curie
---

## List all Physicists

{% for itm in site.physicists %}
    {{ itm }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I must not have explained my issue very well. I want a single page that shows all the blog posts that have mentioned the particular person. The page that you link shows that tags are accessed in `site.tags.TAG`. I would like to do it similarly with people. Are tags treated differently than other frontmatter metadata?

Comment: Do you want to reach a match between `site.physicists` and `page.people`? If yes you need to match the physicists and the peoples inside the loop